# Right justify InputGestureText og menuitem

Tags: c#, wpf, menuitem

DO you have any idea on how to right justify a menuitems InputGestureText?
My menu's InputGestureText will always display left-justified just like this:

> File
>   New...............Ctrl+N
>   Open.............Ctrl+O
>   Options.........Alt+Enter
>   Exit................X

What I'm trying to do is to display it like this:

> File
>   New.......................Ctrl+N
>   Open....................Ctrl+O
>   Options.............Alt+Enter
>   Exit...............................X

I tried doing InputGestureText.PadLeft() but my font-family is proportional so it will still result to

> File
>   New ............Ctrl+N
>   Open...........Ctrl+O
>   Options......Alt+Enter
>   Exit..................X

I tried to research some ways to make it possible but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify the style of the [menu item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747082%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).
It should be sufficient to copy it and just change the alignment on the element with the name
InputGestureText, we use a ContentPresenter instead of a TextBlock, but both should work.

```
<ContentPresenter
  Grid.Column="2"
  Margin="16,0,6,0"
  x:Name="InputGestureText"
  Content="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}"
  HorizontalAlignment="Right"
  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably change the [`Template`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.template.aspx) of menu items via a `Style` so that the container of that section aligns its content to the right.

Comment: Thanks! Somehow, after working around a bit with Templates and Styles, I got it. This was my first time with Styles.. *phew*